# Trying to add an array to list Item in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and am having an issue. I have add table rows element wherein I am adding rows based on values in the input field.
[image]

Based on this I am trying to add these same values to the List Item option.

[image]

I am trying to add the values to listItemtext options:

Here is the code where I am trying this:

```
export class Confirm extends Component {
      state = {
        rows: [],

        idx: []
      };

      continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Process Form//
        this.props.nextStep();
      };

      back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
      };

      render() {
        const {
          values: {
            Title,
            Details,
            What,
            Why,
            How,
            Status,
            Cost,
            Benefits,
            Kpi_Before,
            Kpi_After,
            Time,
            dateTime,
            Base_Before,
            Target_Before,
            UOM_Before
          }
        } = this.props;

        return (
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <React.Fragment>
              <AppBar size>Confirm Information</AppBar>
              <br />
              <br />
              <List>
                <ListItemText primary="Title" secondary={Title} />
                <ListItemText
                  primary="Details of Best Practice"
                  secondary={Details}
                />
                <ListItemText
                  primary="What is the Best Practice"
                  secondary={What}
                />
                <ListItemText
                  primary="Why was the Best Practice Implemented"
                  secondary={Why}
                />
                <ListItemText
                  primary="How was the Best Practice Implemented"
                  secondary={How}
                />
                <ListItemText primary="Implementation Status" secondary={Status} />
                <ListItemText primary="Cost of Implementation" secondary={Cost} />
                <ListItemText
                  primary="Benefits of the Best Practice"
                  secondary={Benefits}
                />

                <ListItemText
                  primary="Time taken for Implementation"
                  secondary={Time}
                />
                {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                  <ListItemText
                    key={idx}
                    primary="KPI Before Implementation"
                    secondary={Kpi_Before}
```

I am trying to take the values from here:

```
export class KPIDetails_2 extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: [],
    idx: []
  };
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };
  back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  };

  handleChangeRows = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };

  //2
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      Kpi_After: "",
      UOM_After: "",
      Base_After: "",
      Target_After: "",
      dateTime_After: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };

  //3
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  setDate = dateTime => this.setState({ dateTime });

  deleteRow = index => {
    var rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ rows });
  };

  render() {

return (


                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                      <td>{idx + 1}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Kpi_Before"
                          defaultValue={Kpi_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to show whatever values are put in the table above to the list but it is taking just the value of the last column